# Date formatter for sap.m.Text unvisible if the value is empty

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a `sap.m.Label` and `sap.m.Text`. The value I get from back-end is either `NULL` or it's a date object like this `Tue Oct 01 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200`.

I would like to use a formatter to convert `Tue Oct 01 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200` into `Oct 01, 2019` and if the value from back-end is `NULL` then both `sap.m.Label` & `sap.m.Text` should be NOT VISIBLE.

This is my XML:

```
<Label text="{i18n>ZZDATAB}" id="StartDateLbl" 
  visible="{
    path:'itemDetailData>/StartDate',
    formatter:'ui.s2p.srm.sc.approve.util.Formatter.showElementOnUi'
  }">
  <layoutData>
    <sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData minWidth="192" weight="3"></sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData>
  </layoutData>
</Label>
<Text 
  text="{
    path:'itemDetailData>/StartDate',
    formatter:'ui.s2p.srm.sc.approve.util.Formatter.formatDateZ'
  }" 
  visible="{
    path:'itemDetailData>/StartDate',
    formatter:'ui.s2p.srm.sc.approve.util.Formatter.showElementOnUi'
  }"
  id="StartDateTxt" maxLines="0">
  <layoutData>
    <sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData weight="5"></sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData>
  </layoutData>
</Text>
```

My formatter:

```
ui.s2p.srm.sc.approve.util.Formatter.formatDateZ = function (d) {
    if (d === "" || d === null || typeof(d) === "undefined") {
        return "";
    } else if (typeof(d) === "object") {
        var u = new Date(d);
        var s = u.toString();

        var result = s.substring(4, 10) + ", " + s.substring(11, 16);

        return result;
    }
    return "";
};

ui.s2p.srm.sc.approve.util.Formatter.showElementOnUi = function(obj) {
    if (obj === '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Problem: if I debug the back-end and make `itemDetailData>/StartDate` to be empty, the outputs still displays those Labels even thought they should be INVISIBLE:

```
Start Date:
End Date:
```

Comment: hi, if I understand you right: you check obj === '' but your json(?) the backend responses is null and not ''. so try obj === null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Expression Binding](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/da/f6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0/content.htm?no_cache=true).

And you could format your date object with [sap.ui.model.type.DateTime](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.type.DateTime) 
and style medium (e.g. Dec 31, 2019)

```
<Label text="{i18n>ZZDATAB}" id="StartDateLbl" visible="{= ${itemDetailData>/StartDate} !== null}">
  <layoutData>
    <sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData minWidth="192" weight="3"></sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData>
  </layoutData>
</Label>
<Text 
  text="{path : 'itemDetailData>/StartDate', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions:{ style: 'medium'}}" visible="{= ${itemDetailData>/StartDate} !== null}" id="StartDateTxt" maxLines="0">
  <layoutData>
    <sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData weight="5"></sap.ui.layout:ResponsiveFlowLayoutData>
  </layoutData>
</Text>
```